# Click Once For All Elements In Same Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write code that will add another row to a form automatically. It should only do this once for each form input with the class lastName.

The below code works. But it executes more than once. I want the code to only execute once for each form input with the class lastName. I am inexperienced with jquery and javascript, so I am unsure of how to approach this problem.

```
    function AutoAdd() {
    $('.lastName').focus(function(e){
    $('#add_new',pupils_form).parent().before(pupils_row);

    AutoAdd();
    });
    };
    AutoAdd();
```

Comment: Why are you calling AutoAdd function inside focus callback function?

Comment: I am inexperienced, and I realize this is not good. I was trying to get it to identify the lastname class in newly added rows, and this was the only way I could do it. It was the only thing I tried that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

```
$('.lastName').one('click', function(e){
      $('#add_new',pupils_form).parent().before(pupils_row);
});
```

Also as you are binding a handler for the inputs you can put the handler outside of the function, note that your function calls itself and runs continuously. If you want to execute the handler on page load you can trigger the event:

```
$('.lastName').focus(function(e){
      $('#add_new',pupils_form).parent().before(pupils_row);
}).focus()
```

---

For dynamically generated elements, you should delegate the event, try the following:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.lastName', function(){
     $('#add_new',pupils_form).parent().before(pupils_row);
})
```

You can use `data-*` attributes, try the following:

```
<input type='text' class='lastName' data-run='go'/>
```

```
$(document).on('focus', '.lastName', function(){
     if ( $(this).data('run') == 'go') {
           $('#add_new',pupils_form).parent().before(pupils_row);
           $(this).data('run', 'stop')
     }
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this earlier, but it doesn't work fully. The problem is that the added row contains a new lastName class. And this code doesn't seem to work for the new rows.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure about the right order to use everything mentioned above. If I use all three pieces of code at once, it doesn't work. I have also tried other combinations and it didn't work either.  Please can you let me know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: @RicardoCollins They are three different handlers, you should use only one of them, try the last one :)

Comment: If I only use the last one on its own, it does not limit the action to once per instance of the class. I am sorry if I am missing something obvious – I don't have enough knowledge to really grasp what's going on yet :-)

Comment: @RicardoCollins You wanna bind the event once for every element with class of `lastName` separately or all of them?

Comment: I am not too sure about the definition of bind, but I'll read up on it now. Each instance of lastName should be allowed to be clicked on only once. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @RicardoCollins yes, it does, you can add a data attribute to the inputs, try the the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are having an **infinite** call stack here.  your `AutoAdd` will call itself again and again and ...

Comment: I originally tried the code proposed by Raminson below, but it didn't work on new rows added by jquery. This was the only code I tried that seemed to work on newly added rows. I realise this is wrong, and I am trying to come up with a solution that works. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: try @Raminson 's updated answer, $.on would be the one that works

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to run your `AutoAdd` function on newly created rows, you can use jQuery's `on()`-function instead of `focus()`:

```
$('#the-form').on('focus', '.lastName', function () {
    $('#add_new',pupils_form).parent().before(pupils_row);
});
```

`on()` actually attaches to the form (you'll wanna change the selector `#the-form`) and listens to events that bubble up from children of said form.